# How to edit Auto layout Constraints properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, ios-autolayout

i am new to constraints ,i had trying auto layout more than 5 hours ,but only little bit i have understood.

->finally i gave my view to **reset to suggested constraints**
that run the app,70% of my screen placed properly but problem is 
[image: labels didn't display as per the standard width]

This is previous image ....[image]before run the app. any tell me to adjust it...

Debug Area:

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa168b30 H:[UILabel:0xa419bd0'New User? Please'(109)]>
```

Comment: seems you have a constraint with specific height of 109, and this is breaking. this view looks pretty simple, it would be better to see how this whole screen looks like. You should take a look on constraints tutorials: (http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Comment: If "New User? Please", "Sign Up" and "here" this three are in same label then you have to set leading space, trialling space and top space constraints and  if your label height is same for all the devices then you have to give height constraint else you have to set bottom space constraint.

Comment: This three is separate two label and one button @RupalPatel

Comment: Ok. then you need to set this three in one view. 
1) View Constraints are: Top Space, Leading Space, Trailing Space and Height Constraints
2) Label "New User? Please" Constraint is: Top Space, Leading Space, Height and Weight Constraints
3) Label "here" Constraints are:   Top Space, Trailing Space, Height and Weight Constraints
4) Button "Sign UP" Constraints are: Top Space, Leading Space, Trailing Space and Height Constraints

Make sure when you set the constraint and at that time "Constrain to margins" is checked then you have to unchecked that.

Comment: @RupalPatel thanks for the clear info now i understood it...

Comment: and re correct your answer weight ! its width...

Comment: and please add full screen shot of the screen and on which device you are testing

Comment: yes sure @VarunNaharia i understood your query...

Answer (score 0):

Adding correct constraints to any screen takes many things to consider but I think you can solve your problem for now by just adding one more width constraint to signup button. There are few more changes that you might have to do but without seeing full screen shot it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

AutoLayout is expalined clearly and concisely in this.
http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/